# Formatar arquivo .csv em bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

Estou com o seguinte problema: copiei os dados de uma tabela da Internet para um arquivo de texto. O objetivo é transformar esse arquivo para o padrão .csv em inglês (separado por vírgulas e com separador de decimais sendo o ponto final), além de algumas outras formatações. Exemplo do arquivo:

```
Data    Fechamento  Variação    Variação (%)    Abertura    Máxima  Mínima  Volume
30 Abr 2020     2,00    0,76    61,29%  1,99    2,10    1,80    152.100
29 Abr 2020     1,24    -0,44   -26,19%     1,28    1,71    1,20    125.700
```

Meu código está assim:

```
echo -e "Arquivo nao-estruturado: \c"
read nome_arq

arq=$(<$nome_arq)

arq=$(echo $arq | sed 's/%//g')
arq=$(echo $arq | sed 's/()//g')
arq=$(echo $arq | sed 's/\.//g')
arq=$(echo $arq | sed 's/\+//g')
arq=$(echo $arq | sed 's/ Abr /_04_/g')
arq=$(echo $arq | sed 's/ Mar /\_03_/g')
arq=$(echo $arq | sed 's/\,/\./g')
arq=$(echo $arq | sed 's/\ /\,/g')

append="_clean"
echo -e $arq >> $nome_arq$append
```

Entretanto, a saída do script não está com quebra de linha, ou seja, o arquivo de saída só contém uma única linha:

```
Data,Fechamento,Variação,Variação,Abertura,Máxima,Mínima,Volume,30_04_2020,2.00,0.76,61.29,1.99,2.10,1.80,152100,29_04_2020,1.24,-0.44,-26.19,1.28,1.71,1.20,125700,
```

Ideias para que as linhas do arquivo original se mantenham no arquivo de saída?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifiquei um pouco, fazendo uma cópia do arquivo e alterando a cópia.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "Arquivo nao-estruturado: \c"
read nome_arq

cp $nome_arq $nome_arq"_clean"
arq=$nome_arq"_clean"

sed -i 's/%//g;s/()//g;s/\.//g;s/\+//g;s/ Abr /_04_/g;s/ Mar /\_03_/g;s/\,/\./g' $arq
sed -r -i  's/[[:space:]]+/,/g' $arq
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, fera, valeu!

Answer (score -1):

Esse arquivo csv pode ter sido editado no Windows. E, basicamente, o Linux "enxerga" o fim de linha de forma diferente do Windows.

Tente isso:

```bsh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install dos2unix
dos2unix arquivo.csv
```

Att.

Comment: Fala, irmão. Gerei o csv em ambiente linux mesmo.